# Are there any special English words describing indexed items which are displayed first word last?

Tags: single-word-requests

The indexes in the back of some books contain items which are listed with the first word at the end, e.g.:

- An entry for "The Golden Goose" would be listed as "Golden Goose, The".
- An entry for "baseball teams" might be listed as "baseball teams", but also as "teams, baseball".

Are there any English words to describe such a reversal, or to call index items which are displayed in reverse, or to call an index which contains such items?

Comment: These are just the rules for creating an alphabetical index. Just curious, why do you think there is a word for this?

Comment: @JLG: There *could* have been a word for it, but in practice I don't think there is (apart from maybe *alphabetised*, or *indexable*).

Comment: Rather than first-word-last, it's actually kind of Most-important-word-first. All the preceding words then move to the end, separated by a comma from the actual end of the phrase.

Comment: @Kris: Yes, but "most important word" is context-dependent. Also, even if OP's *goose* were to be the "primary keyword", you might still want to consider whether *golden* is worth treating as a "secondary keyword" (giving *"Goose, Golden, The"*). I think mostly you'd probably decide against that, and index it as *"Goose, The Golden"* (in a book where geese where significant enough to have several entries in the index).

Comment: There would be: 'goose that laid golden eggs, The', and 'golden eggs, The goose that laid'.

Comment: Yes. A keyword is always context-dependent. Pl also see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it's *index style*, but there are many different implementations.

For example, there could be a book out there somewhere with consecutive index entries for *"Goose, Golden, The"*, and *"Goose, Girl, The"* - it all depends on which "keywords" are most important in the context of the particular publication.

The process of determining your keywords, and re-arranging the words in each entry to ensure the important ones come first, is called [Alphabetization](http://www.anindexer.com/about/alph/alphindex.html)

Incidentally, *Golden Goose, The* - is far less common than *Goose That Laid the **Golden Egg**, The*.

Comment: It's both.  Aesop wrote _The Goose That Laid The Golden Egg_, but _[The Golden Goose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Goose)_ is found in the Bros. Grimm collection.

Comment: @J.R. Yeah, but if you add together all the **Golden Eggs** and **Golden Egg** laid, they're [far more common](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+golden+goose%2Claid+the+golden+eggs%2Claid+the+golden+egg&year_start=1840&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) than the **Golden Goose** - and I bet at least some of the people talking about a golden goose think it lays golden eggs (which of course, [it doesn't](http://storynory.com/2008/05/12/the-golden-goose/) - its value being in its golden feathers).

Comment: " ... determining key-words ..." is not aphabetization. The latter, in simpler terms, is what we know as sorting.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Huh?  What does that have to do with anything?  Either one is a valid example for a title, contrary to your answer's final assertion.  It matters not how many Eggs, Golden are laid by the story's title character. :^)  Moreover, according to [your own Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+golden+goose%2Claid+the+golden+eggs%2Claid+the+golden+egg&year_start=1963&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3), the Goose, Golden is making a resurgence of sorts.

Comment: @J.R.: If you insist. Fact remains that even today, *golden eggs/eggs* outweighs *goose* by almost 2:1, and I still think some/many/most of the modern references to *golden goose* are mistakes. Look at the recent rise in [killed the golden goose](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=killed+the+golden+goose&year_start=1963&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) (it doesn't die in the Grimm tale, obviously).

Comment: @FF: If I insist?  Yes, I insist that _The Golden Goose_ is a valid example of a title.  (So are _The Gold Bug_, _The Golden Compass_, _The Snow Goose_, and _The Goose Is Loose_.)  The O.P. said, "an entry for the _The Golden Goose_ would be listed as _Golden Goose, The_."  That's true; that's how it would be listed, no matter what other stories might be more common.  (Some modern references to _The Golden Goose_ may be "mistakes," as you claim, but, given the context, it's hard to see how this instance could be tagged as erroneous).

Comment: @J.R.: I didn't mean to imply *The Golden Goose* isn't a valid example of a title. But Google Books says of the 56K entries for those three words, over 17K of them are preceded by *kill* or *killed*. The Grimm goose never dies so I take that as evidence that at least one in three *published writers* confuse it with Aesop's goose. For Google Internet the error rate is higher, at 310K *kill/killed* out of 729K, and I'd expect spoken usage to be even worse. The fact that it *may* be used correctly doesn't invalidate my point that it's very often used mistakenly.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Whether or not the titles are oft-confused was never pertinent to the O.P.'s question or initial conversation – that's all I've been saying.  After you typed, "it wasn't actually The Golden Goose;" I simply tried to gently clarify, "It's both."

Comment: @J.R.: I fully accept my point was never really pertinent to the O.P.'s question. In retrospect I should probably have taken a leaf out of J.R's book and added it as a comment. Certainly *his* comment is more relevant to his answer than mine was, and it doesn't seem particularly odd to me that the first comment under an answer should be from the answerer himself. It's a device I shall try to remember and make use of myself in future.

Answer (score 5):

It can be called 'keyword-first'. In your example, the initial *The* is moved to the end so that the really significant word now comes first and therefore the entry will appear in the sorted index at the appropriate place (rather than under 'The').

Both *baseball* and *teams* are keywords (words you would want to lookup, which is what an index is for), so *baseball teams* appears twice: as it is, as well as rearranged on the kwd *teams*.

Comment: disclaimer: I'm an experienced abstracter-indexer for STM, but no authority on the subject. This is my personal 2c.

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, words like "the" and "an" are called "stop words" in the world of library science. Wikipedia has a good article on them here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words

Comment: I had a feeling that, if such a term existed, the answer might come from someone with a degree in library science. When I did some preliminary research on this question, I couldn't find a term for this kind of cataloging, but I did run across several detailed standards for that sort of thing, like [this one](http://www.ifla.org/files/cataloguing/icp/icp_2009-en.pdf).  Interesting stuff.

Comment: Thank you for the link; I was not aware of that particular standard. We only covered AACR2 and touched on its replacement, RDA (I took cataloging before RDA was official).